# How to open Android apk file directly on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an apk file which I have downloaded from the Internet,
If it's possible can you delineate it in detail.
I am new to Android Development so any relevant information would be helpful.
Thanks.
**My question doesn't focus on the source code of the apk file.I want to open the apk file directly in Android Studio!**

Comment: Nope, would make some angry devs if it was that easy to decompile their APKs :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 11):

You are searching for the "APK Analyzer" feature.

See menu **Build** -> **Analyze APK..**

It is included since Android Studio 2.2.